# Can SQL Server 2008R2 SSIS packages access SQL Server 2012 databases with driver updates only?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, ssis

We have two products running on SQL Server that we will be upgrading to SQL Server 2012 on a staggered schedule. Product B uses SSIS packages (using ODBC drivers) to extract data from Product A's database.

The scenario would be to move Product A to SQL Server 2012 first, with product B to follow in the coming months.  Product B would continue to run in a 2008R2 environment while Product A would be moved to a new SQL Server 2012 environment.

The hope is that there would not be a need for package changes and that installing the new   ODBC Driver (Microsoft ODBC Driver 11) on the 2008R2 SSIS environment would allow the packages to execute against Product A.

EDIT - The package would remain in the SQL Server 2008 format and would be using the SQL Server 2012 Database as it's source.

Does anyone know if this is in fact viable or are there known issues that would require package changes?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Matt

Comment: To clarify: the package remains in 2008 format and simply needs to use a 2012 database as its source?